# javaj: input / if statement malfunctioning

Tags: java, console, readline, if-statement

Having a slight problem with the following block of code:

```
newusr = c.readLine("New user? ");
if (newusr == "y") {
    System.out.println("IF");
    usnm = createNewUser();
    usnm = loginToClient();
}
else {
    System.out.println("ELSE");
    usnm = loginToClient();
}
```

Basically, when i enter the single character "y" to the prompt, it takes me to the else case and thusly straight to the loginToClient method. What's going on; is the "y" in a different encoding or something?

c is a console.

Comment: Try outputting newusr to the screen, what do you see?  Just for fun, try outputting the length of newusr.  You might be surprised.

Comment: `==` compares two references to an object i.e. are they the same object. `.equals()` can conmpare the *contents* of two objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to campare Strings in java you use equals, like this:

```
...
if (newusr.equals("y"))
...
```

Comment: I feel so stupid, thanks. I actually knew I should have used this, I don't know why i didn't or didn't see this...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do a `if(("y").equals(newusr))` and check?

This will also avoid `NullPointerException` if you do not enter a value.

Answer (score 0):

The code `newusr == "y"` will compare the memory location of `newusr` variable with `"y"`. Which will fail.

You should be comparing the objects using `.equals()` method.